# Understanding migrations in Realm - Swift

Tags: swift, realm, database-migration

I'm trying to understand migrations, can someone describe situations where migrations are required?

For instance let's pretend for a moment that an app has been released and the following `Realm` objects were used but now version 2 needs to be released and a new `Realm` object was added to this new version, do I need a migration?

#### Version 1

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item:Object{
    dynamic var productName:String = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
}


import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class ItemList: Object {
    dynamic var listName = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    let items = List<Item>()
}
```

#### Version 2

Version 2 needs a new object.

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item:Object{
    dynamic var productName:String = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
}


import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class ItemList: Object {
    dynamic var listName = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    let items = List<Item>()
}

// New object for version 2
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class NewObjec:Object{
    dynamic var someString:String = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
}
```

Do I need to create a migration if existing objects didn't change but an extra object was added?

In general, can someone describe the situations where migrations are needed?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in this case you don't need to perform a migration. You only need to perform a migration in case existing objects need to be changed (adding/removing properties of existing Realm model classes).

If you add a new class to Realm, you don't need to perform a migration.

In most cases, Realm can automatically perform the migration and all you need to do is increase your schema version by 1. However, if you are for example combining two existing properties into a new one, you need to handle that manually in your migration block.

Comment: @ Dávid Pásztor - Thank you for the clarification. One quick question. When is recommended to define a migration in your project, as soon as you start using `Realm` or until is needed? In other words, do you usually add the migration code as soon as you start using 'Realm' in a project or you wait until a migration is required.

Comment: I usually add the migration code as soon as I start using Realm, since usually in the beginning you end up changing your Realm models quite a bit, so it makes sense to do it right away. However, you **don't need to** add a migration block until you actually have a Realm database with entries in your app and you want to change your models.

Comment: Got it. Now, if define your migration code as soon as you start using Realm, do you start with `schemaVersion: 0`  or `schemaVersion: 1`? Thanks.

Comment: Your schema version is 0 initially, so the first time you run your project with your Realm classes already defined, it will be 0. You only need to change it to 1 the next time you make changes in your object models. Anyways, you shouldn't really about this, you can start your schemaVersion with any natural number, it doesn't really make a difference. If you want to know more about migrations, have a look at the [official documentation of migration](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#defining-migrations).

Answer (score 5):

No, you should update the schema version because the Realm schema has been updated, but you don't have to add a migration block.
You could consider Realm as a real database, so in this case it's like your adding a new "column".

In [this](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#performing-a-migration) realm doc section you can find the following block:

```
// Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
// a schema version lower than the one set above
migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
  // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
  if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
    // Nothing to do!
    // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
    // And will update the schema on disk automatically
  }
})
```

You can omit the migration block, updating the Realm version if you're just adding/removing properties:

```
Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 2)
```

As you can see, they say you have to update schema version, then it will automatically update the realm schema adding new (or removed) properties.

In case you're gonna make "special" changes, you have to fill the migration block with you're logic.
Take a look at this:

**Version 1:**

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var firstName = ""
    dynamic var lastName = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
}
```

**Version 2:**

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var fullName = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
}
```

In this case, you're not just adding fullName and removing firstName, lastName, but you're combining them, so it is necessary a custom logic.

```
migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
  if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
    // The enumerateObjects(ofType:_:) method iterates
    // over every Person object stored in the Realm file
    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Person.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
      // combine name fields into a single field
      let firstName = oldObject!["firstName"] as! String
      let lastName = oldObject!["lastName"] as! String
      newObject!["fullName"] = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }
  }
})
```

In conclusion, you need to update schema version every time you update your Models, but you don't need to write a migration block if you're just adding/removing properties.

Edit: Thanks to [Dávid Pásztor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4667835/d%C3%A1vid-p%C3%A1sztor) for suggestions

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good explanation. Quick question, is there a way to test the app after the migration in a way that silulates what users will see after updating to version 2? Would the following process be enough for testing version two before sending it to the appstore for approvals... 1. Delete the testing app version from your phone, 2. Download the app from the appstore, 3. Connect phone and test in XCode. Thanks

Comment: Yeah. I have tags in my git repo for each migration I do.
When I have to test the migration, I usually install my old app version and I use it a bit (just for saving something in realm), then I install the latest (with latest realm migration), so I can simulate what will happen for other users.
I don't know if there's a better way but I'd be interested in.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Comment: @ChristianAscone I have just ran some quick tests and your answer is partly incorrect. When adding a new Realm model class, migration is NOT needed. I liked your example of when a migration is needed, but for the case in question, you don't need to perform one.

Comment: Are you sure? I faced some problems when adding new properties in my projects, that's why I perform migration every time, but what you say is very interesting.
Could you post a doc reference? So I can take a look and update my answer.
Thank you very much

Comment: Updated the answer with @DávidPásztor suggestions

Comment: @ChristianAscone I didn't look at the docs, I just ran tests myself by adding a new model class and checking if I get a migration needed exception, which didn't happen. When you add new properties to existing classes, you need to run a migration, that is correct. But the question was about adding a new model class and not about changing an existing one.